# VTK: Put Label/Text near points in the 3d plot

Tags: vtk

I have written a code which plots multiple 3d points as spheres. I want to add some text near each sphere in 3D to mention some info about each point. But I have vtkPoints to store points positions which doesn't have GetOutputPort which I need in labelMApper (and also used glyph3d to make spheres)

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkLabeledDataMapper> labelMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLabeledDataMapper>::New();
labelMapper->SetInputConnection( vtkpoints->GetOutputPort() ); // No GetOutputPort()
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor2D> labelActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor2D>::New();
labelActor->SetMapper(labelMapper);
renderer->AddActor(labelActor);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should construct a vtkPolyData from the points and set it as Input to the label mapper.

Something like this:

```
vtkNew<vtkPolyData> labelPolyData;
labelPolyData->SetPoints(labelPoints);
labelMapper->SetInput(labelPolyData);  // Note: If you're using VTK from master (6.x), this is SetInputData(...)
renderer->AddActor2D(labelActor);
```